# Nginx reverse proxy not loading resources from another port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

My nginx root is **/usr/share/nginx/html/** and my Node.js App is at **/root/app/**. But the reverse proxy **searches for the app at nginx root.**

I used the following location block.

```
location /t {
  rewrite ^/t/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

And changed the base uri in the app's config to

```
baseURI: '/t'
```

But I get a blank page, **but the title bar says "*AppName*"**

Here is the nginx error log

```
2017/10/26 16:41:43 [error] 3585#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /t HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/t", host: "139.59.46.93"
2017/10/26 16:41:43 [error] 3585#0: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /t HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/t", host: "139.59.46.93"
2017/10/26 16:41:43 [error] 3585#0: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t"
2017/10/26 16:41:43 [error] 3585#0: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t"
2017/10/26 16:41:45 [error] 3585#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /t/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "139.59.46.93"
2017/10/26 16:41:45 [error] 3585#0: *5 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /t/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "139.59.46.93"

##### Ignore above errors. Forgot to use public IP

2017/10/26 16:43:45 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/main.749f8f8f.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:45 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:45 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/main.5957a012.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:45 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:48 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/main.749f8f8f.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:48 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:48 [error] 3620#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/main.5957a012.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:48 [error] 3620#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/main.749f8f8f.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/main.749f8f8f.css HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/js/main.5957a012.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /static/js/main.5957a012.js HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
2017/10/26 16:43:50 [error] 3620#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.206.123.228, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "139.59.46.93", referrer: "http://139.59.46.93/t/"
```

<del>How can I successfully reverse proxy without moving my app from /root/app to the nginx root?</del>

**UPDATE :**

On viewing the source of the page, I can see that nginx is trying to load resources from **/static/js** and **/static/css** at http://139.59.46.93 when it should be loading them from http://139.59.46.93**:3000**

So it is basically proxying the port, **but not the resources**.

How do I pass the resources too?

Comment: Have you looked at the Nginx [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) command? Your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: What do the nginx debug logs say?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `/t` in `location`, but rewrites `^/t/(.*)`, so nginx doesn't rewrite request to `/t` and it is passed to your app *as is*.

In general, you should always use trailing slash in `location` directive that should match directory (unless you're absolutely sure, you don't need it).

Also there is a shortcut for this common case to replace location prefix in nginx. Try this one:

```
location /t/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    # note this slash --------------^
}
```

Documentation on [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) says:

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> - If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

Nginx will replace `/t/` in *location* directive with `/` from *proxy_pass* directive.

Probably you have to change app's `baseURI` to `/t/` too.