# Revese proxy fails to forward requests to port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server where I want setup a reverse proxy with nginx to handle HTTPS traffic to an app in a docker container. Below is the config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. It is based on [this guide](https://www.supereasy.com/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-https-reverse-proxy-easily/) and the ssl setup done automatically by certbot for the default config file.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
 }

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

   location /doccano/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

This setup fails to properly redirect traffic, though. When I open up `example.com/doccano`, only a spinning wheel shows up. It is trying to load resources, but these are not properly forwarded, as `/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows below. This is similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/880532/nginx-reverse-proxy-not-loading-resources-from-another-port), but I am not missing the trailing `/` and it still does not work. I opened up port 8000 to check if the app is the problem, but it works fine there. How do I set this up properly?

```
2023/03/07 09:06:37 [error] 15264#15264: *310 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/c296893.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/c296893.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
2023/03/07 09:06:37 [error] 15264#15264: *310 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/b152b18.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/b152b18.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
2023/03/07 09:06:37 [error] 15264#15264: *312 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/831ddf8.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/831ddf8.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
2023/03/07 09:06:37 [error] 15264#15264: *313 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/6c3c49a.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/6c3c49a.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
2023/03/07 09:06:38 [error] 15264#15264: *310 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/b152b18.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/b152b18.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
2023/03/07 09:06:38 [error] 15264#15264: *310 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/_nuxt/6c3c49a.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: my_ip_v6, server: , request: "GET /static/_nuxt/6c3c49a.js HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/doccano/"
```

Comment: https://github.com/doccano/doccano/issues/1878

Comment: Your backend needs to be configured with the proper base url, but that currently seems not to be trivial with doccano. An easier alternative would be to use a subdomain instead.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me resolve the issue. It is unfortunate that doccano is not easily configurable for such a setup.